# Chakra UI intellisense not working in VS Code

Tags: javascript, vite, chakra-ui

I have installed the latest version of ChakraUI (v 2.8.2) using Vite (v5.0.8) Javascript template in VS Code. When I start typing OR type "ChakraProvider" or the name of any other chakra component vs code does not show any intellisense suggestions at all. Even after I manually import a component, other components are not shown if I press ctrl+space in the import statement.

However, if I use the typescript template then the intellisense works perfectly. All the components and the prop suggestions are shown.

If anyone else is facing the same issue and knows about a workaround for the javascript template then please please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the culprit. I had installed the extension "JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly" by Microsoft which was causing problems with vs code intellisense. After I disabled it everything is working fine now.